# How to customize TradingView.widget in Flutter InAppWebView?

Tags: flutter, tradingview-api, flutter-inappwebview

I want to customize my TradingView chart widget which is in a `InAppWebView` widget. I can display the chart, However, I want to change background color, font and the price scrollbar's type of the chart widget. How can I do this? is there any documentation? I searched a lot in stackoverflow but any of the recommendations was not working. I want to make the chart something similar to binance's chart.

Thanks for all replies!  :)

```
String _testCode() {
    return """
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "exchange",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "toolbar_bg": "#ff7518", <!-- Does Not Work-->
  "hide_side_toolbar": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "save_image": false,
  "show_popup_button": true,
  "popup_width": "1000",
  "popup_height": "650",
  "locale": "en",
  "overrides": {  <!-- Does Not Work-->
        "paneProperties.background": "#ffffff",
  },

  }
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
""";
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InAppWebView(
      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          transparentBackground: true,
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
        ),
        ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
          disallowOverScroll: true,
        ),
      ),
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) async {
        controller.loadUrl(
          urlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: Uri.dataFromString(
              //_generateCode(binanceSymbol),
              _testCode(),
              mimeType: 'text/html',
              encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String _testCode() {
  return """
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget({
    "autosize": true,
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "exchange",
    "theme": "dark",
    "style": "1",
    "toolbar_bg": "#ff7518",
    "hide_side_toolbar": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "save_image": false,
    "show_popup_button": true,
    "popup_width": "1000",
    "popup_height": "650",
    "locale": "en",
    "overrides": {
      "paneProperties.background": "#ffffff",
    }
  });
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
""";
}
```